# Yahoo Finance works fine sometimes but throws a couple nulls

Tags: yahoo-finance

So I have been working on a stock program for quite sometime now. As of yesterday it was working fine. I came back to it this morning and now it gives me null values for some of the variables. Sometimes refreshing the page works but sometimes it does not. I am using YQL. Is there anything that I can do here? Or is this problems with Yahoo? I have included some code that I believe would be the culprit. Percent change, Open, and Volume are the only three that I have a problem with.

```
function getData() {
var url = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql";
var symbol = $("#symbol").val();
var data = encodeURIComponent("select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol in ('" + symbol + "')");

$.getJSON(url, 'q=' + data + "&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store://RjdEzitN2Hceujh3tGHPj6") @*original link broken: http://datatables.org/alltables.env*@
.done(function (data) {

     $("#name").text("" + data.query.results.quote.Symbol);
     $("#date").text("" + data.query.results.quote.Date);
     $("#time").text("" + data.query.results.quote.LastTradeTime);
     $("#result").text("" + data.query.results.quote.LastTradePriceOnly);
     $("#chg").text("" + data.query.results.quote.PercentChange);
     $("#bid").text("" + data.query.results.quote.Open);
     $("#volume").text("" + data.query.results.quote.Volume);

     if(data.query.results.quote.PercentChange.indexOf("+") != -1){

        document.getElementById("chg").className = "w3-text-green";
    }
     else{

        document.getElementById("chg").className = "w3-text-red";
    }

}).fail(function (jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
    $("#result").text('Request failed: ' + err);
});
}
```

Here is the link to the page: http://staging.aeonglobalhealth.com/investors/stock-information/

Comment: If you are asking why you're getting null values back from an API call that you don't control, then that is something you will have to talk to them about. There is nothing that we can do. The only option would be to double check the object to make sure they didn't change the property name.

Comment: But doesn't it seem odd that I get accurate results from half of the data that I call and the last half breaks?

Comment: Yes it is odd, but there's nothing you can do about nulls being provided to you by the API call. The only thing that you can do is with what you do with the data after you receive it. You're doing a `.indexOf()` on the `PercentChange` property, which can be null. You should check if it is null before trying to operate on it.

Comment: Okay, one other thing was that if you change the symbol in the table, you'd have to check the link, and type in another Symbol, i.e YHOO, in the top left corner it works fine, but when you go back to the original stock, ADAT, it still throws null values.

Comment: You'll need to create another question for that. Have you tried debugging anything first?

Comment: I believe it is something to do with the API the stock symbol gives off null values on other sites that offer similar services to what I am trying to accomplish